# Going back to tex live 2021

Tags: beamer

I downloaded text live 2022 today.
A beamer document that compiled before no longer compiles with tex live 2022.
The error is: "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `n'." but I think it has nothing to do with colors since the same file compiled fine on tex live 2021?
Is there any way to fix the problem or to go back to tex live 2021?
Thank you.

Comment: I doubt we can answer that without seeing the code that generates the error. Can you whittle it down to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is not a requirement to delete the previous TeX Live to install a new one, so if you did not delete your TeX Live 2021 when you installed TeX Live 2022 you may be able to get it back by adjusting your PATH settings. But this depends a lot on how you installed TeX Live and your OS (so we can only tell you more if you share more details). There is a historic TeX Live archive at https://www.tug.org/historic/ where you can get frozen versions of older TeX Lives. ...

Comment: ... Note though that TeX Live 2021 has developed since its initial release and it is not guaranteed that the TeX Live from the historic repository is in the same state that your TeX Live was in when you could run your document without errors. Generally speaking I would say it is a much better idea to try and fix your compilation problem than to go back to an older TeX Live. But in order to fix the error you need to tell us more about it. Ideally you share an example document that reproduces the error (and that you are reasonably sure used to compile).

Comment: Also it might be a simple idea to try processing your document on Overleaf as it has 2021 TeX Live. A lot of times users ignore some errors because they see the desired output, but stacking up such errors results in larger and unpredictable errors. So if you strongly think your code was compilable with TL2021; try compiling it on Overleaf and see if you have **any** errors.

Comment: by default if you install texlive 2022 you will still be using texlive 2021 until you set your PATH so to revert to texlive2021 just reset the path. But don't do that. Fix the color error in your document

Comment: Please make a minimal working example and show your logfile so we can see which version of beamer you are using. There was a temporary bug which could result in such an error message, but it has already been fixed https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/759